# Cordova check device internet access

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova

I have an hybrid mobile app based on Angular (Cordova).
I've implemented Google Maps Api and I need to check for internet availability before loading this api.
I've tried with `navigator.connection.type`, but this only tells me if the device is connected to a network, not the internet status. I mean, I can be connected to a wifi network and that network may have no internet access.
So, figuring this out, I've tried this:

```
        $scope.checkInternetAvail = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $.get("http://www.google.com.ec/blank.html").
                done(function(xh){
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }).fail(function(er){
                deferred.reject();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

But when I fire this function, I get a CORS related error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com.ec/blank.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

And so far I'm out of ideas.
Any solution?

Thank's!

Comment: I also had this question on Ionic 3.Thanks.My Idea is:
1=check network.
2=check internet by google site.
3=check my REST Api for server availability